# How to Setup Azure AD Permissions to Send Email via Microsoft Graph in C#?

Tags: email

I am working on a C# project where I need to send emails on behalf of users in my organization using Microsoft Graph. I have set up an Azure App registration and written some code to send emails using the Microsoft Graph SDK. However, I am facing an Authorization_RequestDenied error when trying to send emails. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
public async Task SendEmail(string senderEmail, string recipientEmail, string subject, string content)
{
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);        

    var requestBody = new SendMailPostRequestBody
    {
        Message = new Message
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = new ItemBody
            {
                ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                Content = content
            },
            From = new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = senderEmail } },
            ToRecipients = new List<Recipient> { new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = recipientEmail } } }
        },
        SaveToSentItems = true
    };
    await graphServiceClient.Users[senderEmail].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);
}
```

I suspect this may be related to Azure AD permissions. Could someone guide me on how to correctly set up the permissions in Azure AD to allow my app to send emails via Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely, your suspicion is correct. The Authorization_RequestDenied error you are encountering is likely due to missing or incorrect permissions set in Azure AD for your app registration. To send emails on behalf of users via Microsoft Graph, you need to have the Mail.Send permission set up. Here's how you can set up the necessary permissions in Azure AD:

Navigate to Azure Portal:

Go to the Azure portal, and sign in with an account that has the necessary administrative privileges in the Azure AD tenant.
Access App Registrations:

Once logged in, navigate to "Azure Active Directory" -> "App registrations" -> select your app registration.
API Permissions:

Select "API permissions" from the left-hand navigation menu.
Click on "Add a permission" -> choose "Microsoft Graph" -> select "Application permissions" (since you want to send mail as any user).
Look for the Mail.Send permission under the "Mail" category and add it.
Grant Admin Consent:

After adding the Mail.Send permission, you will need to click on "Grant admin consent for {your directory}" to ensure the permission is granted at the tenant level.
By following these steps, you should be able to set up the necessary permissions for your Azure App to send emails on behalf of any user in your organization using Microsoft Graph. Your code snippet looks correct, and with the right permissions set in Azure AD, it should work as expected to send emails.

#ai-backwash