# Send email using Graph with console application in C# on .NET 7

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, .net-7.0

Using latest Microsoft Graph examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp), with authProvider "Client Credentials Provider"  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp)

Previously I've viewed a similar question [Unable to send email via Microsoft Graph API (C# Console)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77338824/how-to-setup-azure-ad-permissions-to-send-email-via-microsoft-graph-in-c) but I'm still unable to make it work using the latest examples.

My Azure App registration has following API permissions:

[image]

I use code using .NET 7.0 and C#:

```
namespace EmailGraphTesting
{
    public class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await SendEmail.SendEmailAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Me.SendMail; 

namespace EmailGraphTesting
{
    public class SendEmail
    {
        public static string tenantId = "<tenant Id>";
        public static string clientId = "<client Id>";
        public static string clientSecret = "<client secret>";
        public static string[] scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        public static async Task SendEmailAsync()
        {
            var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
            };

            // https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential
            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

            var requestBody = new SendMailPostRequestBody
            {
                Message = new Message
                {
                    Subject = "Outbox Test",
                    Body = new ItemBody
                    {
                        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                        Content = "1st attempt"
                    },
                    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
                    {
                        new Recipient
                        {
                            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                            {
                                Address = "<receiverEmail here>"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                },
            };
            await graphClient.Me.SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error when running the code:

[image]

[image]

I also tried using

```
await graphClient.Users["<email here>"].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

on the last line to no avail.

Comment: the code looks okay but the error is very generic so you need to look more at the response to work out what could be going wrong (there are a number of things it could be). You could create your own debug handler or just run the request through https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/introducing-the-microsoft-graph-developer-proxy-community-preview/ which will allow you to see the full request and response.

Comment: `Users["<email here>"]` are you sure the email you used is correct? I mean the email here should be in format like `xx@tenantName.onmicrosoft.com`, and this account should be assigned a license like M365 E3 which providing email feature.

Comment: With client secret, you can't call graphClient.Me.xxx endpoints because you are not logged on behalf of any user. Do you receive the same exception when calling graphClient.Users["<email here>"].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using ***Client Credentials Provider*** to send email but it looks like *`Me.SendMail`* doesn't support ***Client Credentials Provider*** instead it uses *[Authorization Code Flow Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)*  as per this *[SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270365/unable-to-send-email-via-microsoft-graph-api-c-console)*.

Thanks  **@Tiny Wang** for the comment, you can use ***`Users["{id or userPrincipalName}"].SendMail`*** .

Please grant `Mail.Send` application permission to the registered app and use the below code, it will work for you.

```cs
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var tenantId = "{tenant_id}";

// Values from app registration
var clientId = "{client_id}";
var clientSecret = "{client_Secret}";

// using Azure.Identity;
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var accessToken = await clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(scopes) { });
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var requestBody = new SendMailPostRequestBody
{
    Message = new Message
    {
        Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = BodyType.Text,
            Content = "The new cafeteria is open.",
        },
        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "{Recipient email address}",
                },
            },
        },
    },
    SaveToSentItems = false,
};

await graphClient.Users["*****@*****.onmicrosoft.com"].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

Comment: THIS worked ! I understand the need for a token now; The                                                  **using Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail** is key. It seems Microsoft documentation is lacking for this scenario, as I had gone through every tutorial I could find. Much appreciated...

Comment: After being ran in circles by the llms i finally found this! Works like a charm!